# Media query not applied when needed

Tags: html, css, media-queries

probably this question is stupid as heck, even tho I have spent almost an hour on stackoverflow looking through past questions and another hour on google to see if  I can find my solution yet I've miserably failed.

The problem is that my "media queries" aren't working at all.

Here's my codepen version : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WaXpda

Here's stackoverflow version:

```css
.header-menu-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    left: 12px;
    top: 12px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
    color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.header-menu-toggle::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "Menu";
    height: 45px;
    left: 35px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
}

.header-menu-toggle:hover, .header-menu-toggle:focus {
    color: #CC147C;
}

.header-menu-icon {
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 11px;
    top: 50%;
}

.header-menu-icon::before, .header-menu-icon::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.header-menu-icon::before {
    top: -9px;
}

.header-menu-icon::after {
    bottom: -9px;
}
@media screen and(max-width:768px){
  .header-menu-toggle{
    left:300px; /*middle, just for testing*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="firstPage" class="firstPage">
            <a onclick="openNav()" class="header-menu-toggle" href="#0">
                <span class="header-menu-icon"></span>
            </a>
        
 </div>
```

The problem is that, when the screen width is below 768px, it should move the menu text into the middle. Yet, it's not happening, I've tried resetting the colours, and they are working fine. Just positioning isn't.

Thank you so much for your time spent answering this question, even for reading it.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't edit the word "solved" into the title of a question.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I needed to wait 10 minutes before I could accept the answer, I would blame stackoverflow for this long limit not me. I thought it would be better than leaving this question as it was before, sorry again. Mr.Perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error.

You are missing a space in your query

```css
.header-menu-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    left: 12px;
    top: 12px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
    color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.header-menu-toggle::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "Menu";
    height: 45px;
    left: 35px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
}

.header-menu-toggle:hover, .header-menu-toggle:focus {
    color: #CC147C;
}

.header-menu-icon {
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 11px;
    top: 50%;
}

.header-menu-icon::before, .header-menu-icon::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.header-menu-icon::before {
    top: -9px;
}

.header-menu-icon::after {
    bottom: -9px;
}
@media all and (max-width:768px){
  .header-menu-toggle{
    left:300px; /*middle, just for testing*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="firstPage" class="firstPage">
            <a onclick="openNav()" class="header-menu-toggle" href="#0">
                <span class="header-menu-icon"></span>
            </a>
        
 </div>
```

PS. Sorry about the 2 hours wasted :(

Comment: I use `all` since I usually want the media query to work on print as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew this was a stupid error and easy as hell to fix it ! Thank you so much again, solved! (Silly mistake :P)

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.

Comment: @Quentin I did not know that :( Will remember in the future